# Best way to hard-code a giant array for benchmarking

Tags: c, microbenchmark

I want to hard code a giant array of integers in my program.  I'm doing this because I want to benchmark a sorting algorithm.  If I store the array as a text file and I read it in, then I will be measuring the performance of reading in a reading in a large file + sorting, rather than sorting alone.  I'll be benchmarking file reading later.  I *could* put `int vals[] = {<huge number of values here>}` directly into my `main`, but that tends to crash my text editor, so I was hoping there was some way to put in a separate file.  My there's some way of `#include`'ing it? Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just start the benchmark *after* the file is loaded?

Comment: because it's being inserted into a large testing suite where the execution time of the entire executable is measured.  It's a procedural script that is testing lots of files along with this one, so it's just measuring the whole run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the array in a loop by applying some predictable logic. For instance, in one scenario you could iterate through the array and set the value to (size - index). You can get creative by using other functions like mod / multiple / xor, etc.